# Reading array elements from the same line (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, console

Is it possible to read the elements of an array from the same line (from Console) in **C#**? I know it's possible to read multiple inputs from the console and storing the individual parts in different variables using Split(). But I can't understand how to do it in arrays.

***Code***

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrival.Length; i++)
{
     arrival[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

}
```

For example, I have to enter the elements 34 35 36 37 in the array. If I use the above mentioned code, I have to enter each element in a separate line. But what I need is, if I enter 34 35 36 37 in the Console, it must store each number as an element in the array. How to do this?

Comment: you have to split your Input string (with the string method Split)

Comment: question is not clear enough

Comment: That's the part I can't understand. Perhaps, Could you explain this with an example? BTW I am new to C#

Comment: @madmax whatever you have done, paste it here.

Comment: @madmax it is, check last snippet of my answer

Comment: Why down vote? I just asked my doubt.

Comment: while posting question you didn't show your code (" your own work").. so someone might have downvoted it because of that.. not sure though

Comment: but i can't find a better way to describe my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it in following manner for array of type integer

```
string readLine=Console.ReadLine());
string[] stringArray=readLine.split(' ');
int[] intArray = new int[stringArray.Length];
for(int i = 0;i < stringArray.Length;i++)
{
// Note that this is assuming valid input
// If you want to check then add a try/catch 
// and another index for the numbers if to continue adding the others
    intArray[i] = int.parse(stringArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think it won't work. `int.Parse` accepts string, not `string[]`

Comment: yeah, now it looks better.

Comment: is there any direct way to parse array of string to array of integer?

Comment: by direct you mean `one-liner`? Check my answer and there is parsing of string array to int array in one line (using Linq)

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with question, may be you are looking for this
using System;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string s = "there is a cat";
    // Split string on spaces.
    // ... This will separate all the words.
    string[] words = s.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
    }
}
```

Output will be

```
there
is
a
cat
```

Ref link - http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 0):

you need to read from console, split the input string, convert the splitted strings to your type (here to double), then add them to your own array:

here is the code doing what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace test4
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<double> arrayOfDouble = new List<double>(); // the array to insert into from console

        string strData = Console.ReadLine(); // the data, exmple: 123.32, 125, 78, 10
        string[] splittedStrData = strData.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // trim then parse to souble, then convert to double list
        List<double> dataArrayAsDouble = splittedStrData.Select((s) => { return double.Parse(s.Trim()); }).ToList();

        // add the read array to your array
        arrayOfDouble.AddRange(dataArrayAsDouble);
    }
}
}
```