# Take Array Content in Same Line in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have written a small code, it works right on VS, but the problem arises when it is to be submitted online, so it needs input formatted in same line.

Format needs an N integer taking no of Numbers in List
Next Line needs N no of elements in same line separated by space
the next one should output the sum.
I have done that, but there is an problem, it does not let me input no greater than 87, it gives me NumberFormatException at line 17. To get array content in one line I took it from here: [Reading array elements from the same line (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708788/reading-array-elements-from-the-same-line-c)
Newbie in C#, was doing it in Java.

```
class MyClass {
static void Main(string[] args) {

    int i,k;
    int sum=0;
    int n;

    n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    //Took this code from above link
    string readLine = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] stringArray = readLine.Split(' ');
    int[] intArray = new int[100];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        intArray[i] = int.Parse(stringArray[i]); // line 17
    }

    for (k = 0; k <= n; k++)
    {
        sum = sum + k;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sum);


}
```

Comment: Add try-catch, see the exception. Do you probably want to int.Parse(...) something others than number, or there are space or tabs before or after it.

Comment: There are spaces between every value,they should be in same line. tried try catch,it does not give me exception though,program did not pass online test ,but worked in VS though

Comment: I just copy paste your code, it works, but your SUM is wrong. SUM should `sum=sum+intArray[k]` but the line `intArray[i] = int.Parse(stringArray[i]);` is ok

Comment: Is there a special reason for the redundant data input? The length of stringArray will already tell you the number of items.

Comment: New to C#, i used the code from above link at first for taking the inputs horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the elements in the array of integers. At the moment you are just adding the loop counter to your sum.

```
  var n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
  var stringArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
  var intArray = new int[100];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    intArray[i] = int.Parse(stringArray[i]); // line 17
  }
  var sum = 0;
  for (var k = 0; k <= n; k++)
  {
    sum = sum + intArray[k];
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sum);
```

Test in Console:
3
10 20 300
330

Comment: but why it does not getting beyond 88

Comment: Why 88 ? I already test it until 300 and it is still working.

Comment: You are taking 3 nos,i am taking 100 nos, 1,2,3,...100 but it does not go over 88.

Comment: there is a limit in console.readline : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557889/console-readline-max-length

Comment: Ohh! my bad!! Running fine on Vs,but run time error online,can you tell why did you replace k with intArray[k]; i had tested for few nos,i got the right ans

Comment: just take sample up there, SUM = 10+20+300 right ? and not SUM=0+1+2 ?

Comment: Ok!! Thanks Didn't test that

Answer (score 0):

There is another approach, without n (numbers count). You give only your numbers (10 20 300 ...) then show the SUM :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
...    
var stringArray = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
var sum = stringArray.Sum(number => int.Parse(number));
Console.WriteLine(sum);
```